# Laravel where 'less than' query not showing expected results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to make a database query where I search for all of the items which have a lower current level than low stock level. When running the query I am getting no results and I'm not sure why.

This is my query

```
public static function getLowStockItemsCache()
{
         dd(\DB::table('items')->where('current_level', '<', 'low_stock_level')->get());
    }
```

When I die and dump this I get an empty collection.

In my database I have the following records

[image]

Both of these fields at set at int(11)

If I reverse the query I get all 13 records.

Am I missing something small, as it's confusing me greatly and should be simple.

Comment: try `whereRaw('current_level < low_stock_level')` I guess it is comparing against the string `'low_stock_level'` and not against the column. I Think the third parameter in `where()` must be a value and cannot be a column name.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The third parameter is the value parameter which means it will be escaped when building the query to avoid SQL injection. If you want to compare two columns, you have to specifically tell the Query Builder that that part of the query should not be processed, either by using `whereRaw` to pass the raw SQL condition:

```php
\DB::table('items')->whereRaw('current_level < low_stock_level')->get());
```

Or by using `DB::raw()` for the value only, so it's not escaped:

```php
\DB::table('items')->where('current_level', '<', DB::raw('low_stock_level'))->get());
```

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thank you

Comment: Great. Worked Thanks You!!!

Answer (score -2):

Laravel use 3 step argument on the "where" clause,

```
Pair::where('1st','2nd','3rd')
```

by default the 2nd arg is normally default equal sign, saying the 1st arg is equal to the 3rd arg,

```
Pair::where('name', 'john')->get();

Pair::where('stock', '<', '100')->get();
```

When you find this logics then you understand the "where" tricks